Getting hold of a maximal collection of non-zero vectors $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ in $H$ such that $H_i$'s are orthogonal and $H=\bigoplus_{i\in I}H_i.$

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal A$ be a commutaive unital $C^{\ast}$-subalgebra of $B (H).$ Then there exists a maximal collection of non-zero vectors $\{v_i\}_{i \in I}$ in $H$ such that $H_i : = \overline {\mathcal A v_i}$ are orthogonal to each other i.e. $H_i \perp H_j$ for $i \neq j$ and $H = \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} H_i,$ where $\mathcal A v_i : = \left \{Tv_i\ |\ T \in \mathcal A \right \}$ and $I$ is some indexing set.

This is used in proving some version of spectral theorem which identifies operators in $\mathcal A$ unitarily with multiplication operators of some $L^2$-space $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu).$ If $H$ is a cyclic Hilbert space i.e. if there exists a vector $v \in H$ (known as a cyclic vector) such that $H = \overline {\mathcal A v},$ then it can be shown that $\Omega = \sigma (\mathcal A)$ (the set of all multiplicative linear functionals on $\mathcal A$), $\mathcal F =$ Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and $\mu = \mu_{v,v}$ is a finite positive regular Borel measure obtained from the continuous functional calculus such that $$\left \langle Tv, v \right \rangle = \int_{\sigma (\mathcal A)} \widehat {T}\ d\mu_{v,v}$$ for all $T \in \mathcal A,$ where $\widehat T$ is the Gelfand transform of $T.$ In this case we can find out an unitary operator $U : H \longrightarrow L^2 (\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ such that $U T U^{-1} = M_{\widehat T},$ where $M_{\widehat T}$ is the multiplication operator by $\widehat T.$ The general case where $H$ is not a cyclic Hilbert space is dealt with the fact what I asked above.
Can anyone please shed some light on it? Thanks in advance.

What is your question exactly? You can look at Section 2.4 of the book A short course on spectral theory for a detailed proof of the spectral theorem

EvangelopoulosFoivos$:$ The question is clearly mentioned and highlighted at the very beginning and also in the title. What more do you want me to explain?

The existence of the maximal family makes use of Zorn's lemma: Let $S$ be the set  consisting of all  sets of the form $\mathcal M= \{H_a \colon a \in A\}$ such that each  $H_a$  is an $\mathcal A$-invariant closed subspace, contains a cyclic vector $\xi_a$ (i.e. $H_a = \overline{\mathcal A \xi_a}$) and $H_a \bot H_{a'}$ for $a \neq a'$. It is easy to check that if $(\mathcal M_i)_{i \in I}$ is a chain (with respect to inclusion) in $S$ then $\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal M_i \in S$. By Zorn's lemma, there exists a maximal set of pairwise orthogonal $\mathcal A$-invariant closed subspaces $\{H_i \colon i \in I\}$, such that each $H_i$ contains a cyclic vector $\xi_i$.  It remains to show  that $H= \oplus_{i \in I} H_i$. But if this is not the case then  $K = (\oplus_{i \in I} H_i)^{\bot}$ is  a nonzero $\mathcal A$-invariant closed subspace of $H$ [this is because each $H_i$ is $\mathcal A$-invariant and  $\mathcal A$ is a self-adjoint sub-algebra]. Take any nonzero $\xi \in K$ and let $K_0 = \overline{\mathcal A \xi}  \subset K$. Then $K_0$ is an $\mathcal A$-invariant closed subspace with cyclic vector $\xi$, and $K_0 \bot H_i$ for every $i \in I$. This contradicts the maximality of $(H_i)$.

It is clear that there exists a maximal set ${H_i:i \in I}$ such that $H_i$ contains a cyclic vector. But how do you guarantee that they are orthogonal as well?

By the very definition of $S$: It contains all collections $\mathcal M$ of pairwise orthogonal subspaces $H_a$. Hence the maximal set obtain by Zorn also contains pairwise orthogonal subspaces

Sorry I missed the orthogonality part in the definition of the collection $S.$ Now it's alright. Thanks for your kind help.
